# Storage Access Framework in KitKat4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I just wanna implement this Storage Access Framework in my app.

Could anyone please help help me to find out tutorials, or sample app ?

I really have no idea about Storage Access Framework,  and not able to understand the tutorial. please some one help me..  I am very beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many mobile users who regularly access their files across multiple devices have found that relying on cloud storage just makes life simpler, but many of us don't keep our files stored in just one place. Now Android 4.4 is rolling out a new way to open files within apps that makes accessing all of these providers both easier and prettier. With KitKat's new storage access framework, apps that prompt users to browse for files will open a sidebar navigation menu that lists recent files, available cloud storage providers, and files stored internally.

This new system is far more attractive than the popup window Android apps currently toss up, and it provides a more intuitive experience. Users won't have to enter what appears to be a separate app to load a file. Now, regardless of whether they're pulling data from Dropbox, Google Drive, or their local gallery, they will be presented with a consistent experience.

[More Info](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-storage-access)